# Filter by paired criteria in multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like the below, and would like to filter by matches in two columns.

In the below, I'd like to filter EMILY AND FEMALE, as well as MICHAEL AND MALE. Can I setup some sort of list or dataframe, and use that to filter?

```
Name,Year,Gender,Count
Emily,2000,Female,25952
Emily,2001,Female,34294
Michael,2000,Male,345697
Michael,2000,Female,4
Michael,2001,Male,185029
Michael,2001,Female,5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may indeed define a data frame with cases of interest and then use `inner_join`:

```
toFilter <- data.frame(Name = c("Emily", "Michael"), Gender = c("Female", "Male"))
inner_join(df, toFilter)
Joining, by = c("Name", "Gender")
#      Name Year Gender  Count
# 1   Emily 2000 Female  25952
# 2   Emily 2001 Female  34294
# 3 Michael 2000   Male 345697
# 4 Michael 2001   Male 185029
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I should review my joins again! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
filter( (Name == "Emily" & Gender == "Female") | (Name == "Michael" & Gender == "Male") )
```

Data used:

```
df <- read_csv("Name,Year,Gender,Count
         Emily,2000,Female,25952
         Emily,2001,Female,34294
         Michael,2000,Male,345697
         Michael,2000,Female,4
         Michael,2001,Male,185029
         Michael,2001,Female,5")
```

Comment: That works, but I was looking for a more efficient or flexible way to go about it.

Comment: Don't have the benchmarks, however from experience filtering with joins is not the most efficient/fastest way. In terms of readability/flexibility, that's of course subjective, I understand.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in reverse - i.e. filter out Emily AND Female and Michael AND Male? I've tried `df %>% filter( (Name != "Emily" & Gender != "Female") | (Name != "Michael" & Gender != "Male") )`  but this seems to have the same result as above.

Comment: @LucyWheeler, try this: `df %>% filter(! ( (Name == "Emily" & Gender == "Female") | (Name == "Michael" & Gender == "Male") ) )`